# Coiex API Curl Could not resolve host

Tags: bash, curl, dns, cryptocurrency, cryptoapi

I am trying to do buy/sell orders after some computation in the unix-BASH environment by application of [www.api.coinex.com](http://www.api.coinex.com) data. Therefore, I wrote s simple BASH code to put a market order for DOGEUSDT.
I use the following official guidelines:
[API Invocation Instruction](https://github-com.translate.goog/coinexcom/coinex_exchange_api/wiki/012security_authorization?_x_tr_sl=auto&_x_tr_tl=en&_x_tr_hl=de&_x_tr_pto=nui)
[Place Market Order](https://github-com.translate.goog/coinexcom/coinex_exchange_api/wiki/032market_order?_x_tr_sl=auto&_x_tr_tl=en&_x_tr_hl=de&_x_tr_pto=nui)

-I use VPN  IN MINT 20. Linux.
-The codes to get data work well, but have problems with POST data.

```
    #!/bin/bash

    #A code to put a market order in the www.coinex.com exchange pairs 

    #My Access ID in www.coinex.com  
    access_id="xxxx" 
    #My secrect Key  in www.coinex.com  
    secret_key="xxxx"  
    #Request Url 
    get_url="https://api.coinex.com/v1/order/market" 
    #Any Amount 
    amount="100.0"  
    #Any pair in the Market
    marketpair="DOGEUSDT"  
    #buy or sell
    market_type="sell" 
    #the market price 
    price="0.041" 
    #Get servertime, Tonce is a timestamp with a positive Interger that represents the number of milliseconds from Unix epoch to the current time. Error between tonce and server time can not exceed plus or minus 60s
    tonce=`curl -X GET  https://api.coinex.com/v1/market/ticker/all |  jq .data.date`

    #authorization code using 32-bit MD5 Algorithm Signature
    authorization=`echo -n  'access_id='$access_id'&amount='$amount'&market='$marketpair'&tonce='$tonce'&type='$market_type'&secret_key='$secret_key''|md5sum`

    #Convert authorization to UPPERCASE
    authorization1=`echo ${authorization^^}`

    #Place market order 
    curl     -v  -H  "authorization:'$authorization1'"  -H   "Content-Type: application/json"     -d  '{"access_id":"'$access_id'", "amount": "'$amount'","market":"'$market'",  "tonce": "'$tonce'", "type": "'$market_type'"}'     -X -POST   "'$get_url'"
```

I got following error:

```
    * Could not resolve host: 'https
    * Closing connection 0
    curl: (6) Could not resolve host: 'https
```

**Edition**
I got the following error after running the latest proposals in the comments.

```
`  `++ curl -v -H 'authorization: 5EB8EFD237AC301BB854D32407C39AF8 -' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{
  "access_id": "03391998195A4A3EAD0D6C59336CF1D1",
  "amount": "0.1",
  "market": "ARUSDT",
  "tonce": "1636216102004",
  "type": "sell"
}' --url https://api.coinex.com/v1/order/market
*   Trying 104.18.30.180:443...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to api.coinex.com (104.18.30.180) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Encrypted Extensions (8):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, CERT verify (15):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Change cipher spec (1):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using TLSv1.3 / TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
* ALPN, server accepted to use h2
* Server certificate:
*  subject: C=US; ST=California; L=San Francisco; O=Cloudflare, Inc.; CN=coinex.com
*  start date: Nov  1 00:00:00 2021 GMT
*  expire date: Oct 31 23:59:59 2022 GMT
*  subjectAltName: host "api.coinex.com" matched cert's "*.coinex.com"
*  issuer: C=US; O=Cloudflare, Inc.; CN=Cloudflare Inc ECC CA-3
*  SSL certificate verify ok.
* Using HTTP2, server supports multi-use
* Connection state changed (HTTP/2 confirmed)
* Copying HTTP/2 data in stream buffer to connection buffer after upgrade: len=0
* Using Stream ID: 1 (easy handle 0x562e9c3c3c80)
> POST /v1/order/market HTTP/2
> Host: api.coinex.com
> user-agent: curl/7.68.0
> accept: */*
> authorization: 5EB8EFD237AC301BB854D32407C39AF8 -
> content-type: application/json
> content-length: 140
> 
* We are completely uploaded and fine
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Newsession Ticket (4):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Newsession Ticket (4):
* old SSL session ID is stale, removing
* Connection state changed (MAX_CONCURRENT_STREAMS == 256)!
< HTTP/2 200 
< date: Sat, 06 Nov 2021 16:28:24 GMT
< content-type: application/json
< content-length: 54
< cf-cache-status: DYNAMIC
< expect-ct: max-age=604800, report-uri="https://report-uri.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/beacon/expect-ct"
< server: cloudflare
< cf-ray: 6a9fb1d72a0c6283-OTP
< 
* Connection #0 to host api.coinex.com left intact
{"code": 25, "data": {}, "message": "Signature error"} `
```

`

Comment: Remove all simple quotes (`'`) around each `$variable` in your cURL command line

Comment: I edited the `curl ` line and removed simple quotes, the code prints another error, it prints the first variable `$access_id` values  with an error in `unmatched brace in URL position`.  **code**: `curl -v   -H  "authorization:$authorization1"  -H   "Content-Type: application/json"   -X  --data {"access_id:$access_id", "amount: $amount","market:$market",  "tonce: $tonce","type: $markettype" }      "$get_url" `     **error**: ` curl: (3) unmatched brace in URL position 1 `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the latest reply I  received from the [www.coinex.com](http://%20www.coinex.com) support team, the code must be written in `node` language, they didn’t mention BASH. It seems BASH is not supported.
Also, I found a `python` package to connect with spot pairs at [www.coinex.com](http://%20www.coinex.com). I  traded crypto pairs with this  repository successfully.
https://github.com/imanmousaei/coinexpy

Answer (score 0):

I propose you format your JSON data with `jq` tool. It's a better and sure formatter than bash or whatelse.

Your cURL last line became:

```sh
# The JSON data format for jq command
# Important: $token are not for bash variables but for jq arguments
#            So, DATA_FORMAT must be defined between simple cotes (not double) 
declare DATA_FORMAT='{"access_id": $access_id, "amount": $amount, "market": $market, "tonce": $tonce, "type": $market_type}'

# jq call to format JSON data
# The jq arguments in data format will be replaced by bash variable values (in this example, with the same name) 
declare DATA_CONTENT=$(jq \
        --null-input \
        --arg access_id   "${access_id}"   \
        --arg amount      "${amount}"      \
        --arg market      "${market}"      \
        --arg tonce       "${tonce}"       \
        --arg market_type "${market_type}" \
        "${DATA_FORMAT}" \
    )

# cURL call
curl \
    -v \
    -H "authorization: $authorization1" \
    -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
    -d "${DATA_CONTENT}" \
    --url "$get_url"
```

Comment: Thanks for your propose, I change  the code based on your edition, I got the following new error:                          `{"code": 25, "data": {}, "message": "Signature error"}`

Comment: Is your cURL request is correctly formatted ? You can see it in verbose mode or with `set -x` just before curl call

Comment: I not sure that your `authorization` variable is correctly formatted

Comment: Thanks a lot, I used the official guideline page to code the curl. I added `set -x` and got the following error which I added in the edition of the question.

Comment: Try: Remove ` -` ( space and minus, from `md5sum` command) at the end of authorization token